# Fetch API cannot load > Safari & Firefox > Cloudinary

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios, cloudinary

Here's my problem: even if CORS is enabled on my front-end (React.js), I'm still getting this issue, **only on firefox and safari**. It might also have to do with Cloudinary,the service I'm using to host images online.

- `Request header field User-Agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`
- `Fetch API cannot load due to access control checks.`
- `Failed to load resource: Request header field User-Agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.B — index.js:1588`.

I can see that CORS is enabled because I'm able to see my request successfully and log it to the terminal. To enable CORS, I'm using: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` with `axios`.

If you want to see the error onlne, here's the website: http://fredbste-marie.com

Thanks for your help, I'm quite unsure what is happening here...

[image]

Comment: Remove whatever part of your frontend JavaScript code is trying to add a User-Agent request header to the request.

Comment: I'm using axios and I'm not able to disable the User-Agent request. Should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

The site looks good to me, has the issue been resolved? Inspecting the page only shows
 [these 2 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HNNO.png), though trying to browse directly to the URLs the images are delivered successfuly. Also, I can see them delivered in your page.

Comment: Can you confirm that the site is working as well on safari and firefox? On my side it's not working. Even tho the [request is successful](https://res.cloudinary.com/www-c-t-l-k-com/image/upload/v1574788853/Capture_d_e%CC%81cran_le_2019-11-26_a%CC%80_12.19.53_lfermh.png), images are blocked when the onClick() function is triggered. 
I don't think it's due to images size, since they are max. [500/700ko](https://res.cloudinary.com/www-c-t-l-k-com/image/upload/v1574789208/Capture_d_e%CC%81cran_le_2019-11-26_a%CC%80_12.26.08_ddfoxg.png).